# Как настроить redmine работать с https?

Tags: apache, https, ssl, redmine

Поставил redmine из коробки на ubuntu server. Решил все перетащить на https, прописал сертификаты.

Как теперь redmine заставить работать с https?

Comment: А в чём проблема? Те же настройки, что прописаны для `:80`, прописываем для `:443`.

Comment: <Directory /var/www/redmine>
    RailsBaseURI /redmine
    PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
</Directory> Дописал в default-ssl и не работает

Comment: Этого должно быть достаточно. А что значит "не работает"? Что пишет? Что в логах?

Comment: The requested URL /redmine/ was not found on this server.

Comment: вы используете Passenger?

Comment: да при установки он точно ставился